# Is it possible to grand SSH access (using username and password) to a Centos 7 machine configured with an user using private key to connect?

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, certificate, centos-7

first of all I am not a system engineer (I am mainly a software developer).

I am working on a Centos 7 machine and I have the following doubt.

Using MobaxTerm client I can access to this machine via SSH setting a specific private key certificate (a **.ppk** file).

So when I connect to this machine it ask me for the username. I insert this specific username (that I suppose be related to this certificate) and I can log into the system without asking me the password (this because I have set the previous .ppk certificate).

Ok, it works fine. This user can become **root** performing **sudo su**.

Then I created a brand new user but I cannot use this user to connect to my machine via SSH, infact if I try to insert this user I obtain this error message:

```
login as: myusername
Server refused our key

No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
```

From what I can understand I cannot access because it extect a private key (on client side) also for this user (and I think that in case I have to generate and put the public key also on my remote machine side).

So I have the following doubts:

1. In addition to my first user (that I am succesfully use to perform login and become root setting the private key on my client side) can I enable in some way my secondary user in order to access via SSH using username and password as credentials? (avoiding to use certificate).
2. In case it is possible: it make sense or the use of a certificate is in some way more secure? (also this user is in the **wheel** group so it can become root).
3. If the point 1 is not possible what have I to do to grant the SSH access also to this user? Have I to generate some certificate that must be shared between client and server?

Thank you

Comment: There is no reason you cannot use the same public/private key pair for multiple users, it's just not best practices, but if OpenSSH has been configured to reject password authentication then it's impossible to use a username and password without the reconfiguration of the server.  I point out you are not the server administrator so that likely is NOT possible, or if's technically possible, likely not the best idea if this is for work.

Comment: @Ramhound In this scenario it's perfectly fine to use the same public/private key pair for multiple remote machines and/or remote users as long as the the private key belongs to the same local user on the client machine.

Comment: @xenoson - I come from a different background, I would not have multiple unprivileged user accounts, I would have a privileged and an unprivileged account which would require its own public/private key pair. However, changes to the OpenSSH configuration, still won’t be possible without permissions to do so

Comment: @Ramhound No reason to log into a root account locally if all you need is a remote root in my opinion. I would say the keypair belongs first to a person and second to a person and local machine combination. Not so much to a specific username. Just because one person is allowed to become root on one remote machine doesn't mean he is allowed root on every remote machine. So you would suggest adding a new local user of the same name as the new remote user and using a new key pair for the authorized public key? Sure, no problem with that. But anyway, no changes to OpenSSH configuration needed.

Comment: @xenoson - I don't log remotely in as root, I login as an account, that is authorized to switch user to root.  There is a big difference

Comment: @Ramhound What exactly is the big difference if you need a root shell on a server?

Comment: The user might have access to sudo and the other one won’t

Answer (score 1):

The public keys that allow access to the SSH server are stored in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server. That is the home directory of the user you use to login on the server. Yes you can copy the whole file, or the individual key from that file from your old user to the new one. An alternative would be to temporarily enable password logins and use `ssh-copy-id` but the result would be the same if you use the same key.